# I'd like to learn about constructing a graph Laplacian, reading material?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, reference-request, graph-laplacian

The author of [these notes](http://people.csail.mit.edu/dsontag/courses/ml14/notes/Luxburg07_tutorial_spectral_clustering.pdf), mentions 3 different graph Laplacians. Each of these creates a different measure of group size when used in spectral clustering. She offers a proof for each, but I would like to read more about constructing a Laplacian. What is written there is a little too terse for me to really understand.

Can anyone recommend some reading that would cover the various choices of graph Laplacian and relate them to their measure of cluster size?

Comment: It's not quite what you're asking for, but if you also happen to have some probabilistic interest, I'd recommend getting a grasp on the basics of random walks (for instance via Frank Spitzer's book). Simple random walk on a weighted graph is then in direct correspondence with graph laplacians, so this perspective gives you both intuition about graph laplacians (I think random walks are easier to think about) and concrete computational tools (mostly via martingale and fourier transform methods).

Comment: My understanding is that the different versions of graph Laplacians just correspond to different versions of inner products on the graph space. For example, if $f,g$ are functions $V(G) \to \mathbb R$, then dealing with the unnormalized Laplacian is like dealing with the standard inner product $\sum_{v\in V} f(v) g(v)$; dealing with the normalized Laplacian is like dealing with the inner product $\mathbb E_{v \sim \pi}[f(v) g(v)]$, where $v$ is sampled from the stationary distribution of the random walk.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou thanks, your right it's not quite the angle I'm looking for, but it might be a good way in regardless. I will get hold of a copy of Frank Spitzer.